# Remoting into my VM?

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, microsoft-virtual-pc

I am currently trying to remote desktop from my local machine into my Virtual PC VM (both running on the same box), but I'm getting this error:

This Computer cannot connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator.

What do I need to have setup on the remote/VM so that I can get to it.

For completeness, I want to do this so I can have a Full Screen VM since I can't get the VM to go full screen (without a black border).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running XP in the VM, be sure and enable "Allow remote users to connect to this computer" under the Remote tab in the System control panel.

Also, check the Windows Firewall control panel in the VM and make sure that Remote Desktop is allowed as an exception (or that Windows Firewall is turned off).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are able to ping the VM from the host.  [This](http://ixbtlabs.com/articles2/cm/virtualization-vpc-vserv-page1.html) article provides an overview of the ranges based on the network type.

Also ensure that you have enabled remote desktop on the VM under

- System
- Remote
- Allow Remote Desktop

Also disable the firewall on the guest VM.

Answer (score 1):

Does your VM get its own IP address via DHCP?  If so, try connecting via the IP address.

Also make sure that your VM is configured properly (i.e. terminal services is running)